# Windows 7 doesn't turn off

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion DV 6500 and I have installed Windows 7 on it. During the installation of the OS I noticed that the PC doesn't reboot itself when necessary.

The same thing happens now that the OS is installed. I can't shutdown or reboot the PC. I have tried installing Ubuntu and everything works fine. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you installed the required device drivers, an incompatible driver, can prevent windows from shutting down

Comment: Yes I have installed all

Answer (score 0):

Re-install Windows 7 and do not install any drive, and then try to turn off the PC.
I believe this should be the probelm about one of your drives.

Comment: Already done...I don't know what else I could try...